# Stylus change any CSS for website code - manual copy from old profile

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, css, waterfox

I use [Stylus](https://add0n.com/stylus.html) for [Waterfox](https://www.waterfoxproject.org/en-US/) to fix all the issues with websites. Waterfox is effectively Firefox without getting rid of what made Firefox truly customizable: it's native extensions.

Recently an extension corrupted my profile and I had to semi-rebuild my Waterfox profile. I know all about *where* the profiles for Firefox/Waterfox are stored though I'm not certain where the customizations *per site* created via Stylus are stored. Where do I find those customizations so I can port them over to the new/fixed profile?

Comment: `stylish.sqlite` in your profile directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to the file (and the file itself may be subjective) is long and contains much subjectivity.

- C:\
- users\
- [User]\
- AppData\
- Roaming\
- Waterfox\
- Profiles\
- 56.0\
- storage\
- default\
- moz-extension+++897c31ec-33b2-42f7-ace9-ff6dbb0d887a\
- idb\
- 489858440shtsyil.sqlite

I found the file by making a chance to a site and then seeing which file in the profile was the last updated (or among the last), opened it up in Notepad++ and found the CSS I had added for that site.